# How to access the img value? javascript

Tags: javascript, image, if-statement, png, angular7

I have an array of objects with several properties, one of them is called 'file', of which there are two types as represented below

```
const products = [
  {
    functional_id: "2_recharges",
    quantity: 1,
    title: "Coffret empreinte rouge",
    file: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAZAA…em3dIEUUE1O4fn/M8l6v+f6VPgptdk2plAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
  },
  {
    functional_id: "sacs_blancs",
    quantity: 1,
    title: "Sacs blancs",
    file: "data:image/;base64,"
  }
]
```

It's the first time I work with image files and I don't know how to differentiate to create a condition so that only those containing the word 'png' in its value are displayed, in the case of the example the first one, since those that are like the second one don't display any image

I tried to treat them as a string to check if they contained the value string but it doesn't work, as I understand that they are not strings.

If someone can give me an idea of how to create my condition. Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the js [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to check whether the file includes `'png'`.

```js
const products = [{
    functional_id: "2_recharges",
    quantity: 1,
    title: "Coffret empreinte rouge",
    file: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAZAA…em3dIEUUE1O4fn/M8l6v+f6VPgptdk2plAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
  },
  {
    functional_id: "sacs_blancs",
    quantity: 1,
    title: "Sacs blancs",
    file: "data:image/;base64,"
  }
]

const pngImages = products.filter(product => product.file.includes('png'))
console.log(pngImages)
```

Comment: @javascript110899 note that you should probably search something more precise like `image/png;`, as the probability to have `png` characters in this order in the base64 encoded string is not null

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

this simple filter returns you just only those products that have png in file string

```js
products.filter(product => product.file.match('png').length);
```

Comment: This code will lead to an error if there is not a match - `Cannot read property 'length' of null`

Comment: you can just put `?` sign like
`products.filter(product => product.file.match('png')?.length);`
or remove `.lenght`